# Operation that selects a unique representative from each class of associate elements

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, terminology, divisibility

Is there some kind of a standard, uniform, or otherwise natural method for selecting representatives of classes of associate elements in certain rings?  I would be interested in a simultaneous generalisation of positive integers and of unitary polynomials over a field, or of the absolute value function for integers and of the division of polynomials by the leading coefficient.

Is there a standard term for such an operation?

For example, when computing a PGCD of a family of integers, it is customary to look for the positive one, and when computing a PGCD of a family of univariate polynomials, it is customary to look for the unitary one.

(My current context: I am trying to program a generic function to compute the "normalised" PGCD, and I am interested in proper terminology and in any general theory on the subject.)

Comment: I rather doubt it.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it seems closely related to this concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain (The group in your case would be the group of units.)  Then if you have some natural embedding of your ring (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ into $\mathbb{C}$), a good choice of fundamental domain gives you a system of representatives for the associate elements. 

Maybe you could do a similar thing if you take an embedding of the ring of integers of a number field - you'd need to say something about the action of the (maybe infinite) group of units.

Comment: I think that what I outlined might work for any $\mathbb{R}$ (or maybe complex) algebra where you could "compute" sufficiently well a presentation action of the group of units. Note that each unit acts R-linearly, so you actually have a presentation for a matrix representation. Under some assumptions (e.g. finite group of units) it seems possible that there is an algorithm that spits out an explicit formula for a polytopal fundamental domain. Maybe first step would be to try to compute a decomposition into irreducible representations... But idk I'm just speculating.

Comment: Maybe check this out: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0065/f37e12c04af31a700a9b8740a454e2cd3eca.pdf